# Sudden color change in "git log"

Tags: git, git-log

Please consider the following `git log` alias I use:

```
log --date-order --color-moved --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold cyan)%aD%C(reset) %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset)%C(auto)%d%C(reset)%n''%C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)' --all
```

And now, please consider the following screenshot the above alias produces:
[image]
As one can see, in the red circles in the screenshot, there are sudden color changes. Why is that?

I think its an issue with my alias.

EDIT:
Clarification as requested by @eis in the comments: for example, take a look at the first red circle. There is a new branch starting there, right? It starts with yellow `/` and then immediately change to a blue `|`. It should have started with blue.

Comment: I actually cannot see the color changes you mention. All I see is that the colors in general are a mess, probably due to the snapshotting process you've used (jpg). But do note that `--graph` does its own color-changing, to attempt to make the connecting "lines" (`|` `/` etc characters) tie together. ... Ah, the image looks a little clearer now for some reason, and maybe I *can* see just what I mentioned (that the connecting lines are colored).

Comment: @torek Sorry. I've improved the picture quality.

Comment: can you clarify in the question what exactly you mean with "sudden color changes"? what is the expected outcome with your alias and what happens instead?

Comment: @eis I've updated the question. I hope its clear now :-)

Comment: @torek I am sorry, but I don't understand you. Can you please explain again using maybe an example/screenshot/other wording?

Comment: You might be happier using a dedicated Git graphing GUI such as `gitk` or Sourcetree. The `graph` display of `git log` can be hard to read because it lacks the power to show every topological split in the place where it happens.

Comment: @matt Yes, you are correct. But, what I am doing is I am build such a GUI myself (I am learning Rust and this sounds like a fun project). I am currently parsing out the color from the output of `git log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Clarification as requested by @eis in the comments: for example, take a look at the first red circle. There is a new branch starting there, right?

No, there isn't.  The text at this area reads:

```
| * 8760adec - Wed, 23 Mar 2022 22:47:50 -0200 (5 weeks ago)
|/            Red - refaelsh
| * 6a8d1d15 -  Wed, 23 Mar 2022 22:28:12 -0200 (5 weeks ago)
```

The yellow forward slash on the middle line connects from the `*` marking commit `8760adec` to the left-hand-side vertical lines `|` leading down to commit `* 8ddae51a`, indicating that the (single) parent of `8760adec` is `8ddae51a`.

The *start* of the branch is way down off the bottom of the screen and is probably the root commit.  The *end* of the branch is off the top of the screen.  A branch name selects whichever commit is to be considered "the last commit of that branch".<sup>1</sup>

It's true that parent commit `8ddae51a` is on *both branches*, i.e., the one that's being traced down the left edge and also the one for which the yellow slash connects downwards *to* the left edge.  Child commit `8760adec` is only visibly on one branch (although it may be on many others as well; we just aren't viewing them if that's the case).

In any case, the point of the colorization of the `|`, `/`, `\`, etc., characters is just to let you follow them a little better with your eyes.  They *do not* mark specific *branches*.  That's impossible, since many commits are on many branches at the same time.

---

<sup>1</sup>The *first* commit is usually the root commit, which is usually on *every* branch.  Some people like to swap the meanings of first and last here, since Git works backwards: the tip commit, as named by the branch, is the "last" commit but it's always the first you *see* when you have Git look at commits, since Git works backwards.

Comment: Thank you very much @torek! I will read it and re-read and then process it.

Comment: `In any case, the point of the colorization of the |, /, \, etc., characters is just to let you follow them a little better with your eyes.` - Yes, I understand this. But, please take a look again at the screenshot. Lets talk about the top most red circle. We see there a commit `8760adec`, also there is a `/` leading to the commit, and it's color is yellow. My question is why its yellow? It should be Blue.

Comment: As far as `git log --graph` goes, the assigned colors are effectively random. (They're taken out of a circular list whenever it feels like taking another color, but it feels like taking another color at times that make no sense to *you* - and sometimes me. I normally ignore the color of the lines myself.) In this case the line there is yellow because Git assigned "yellow" to the line *below* that line, to which that line connects.

Comment: `In this case the line there is yellow because Git assigned "yellow" to the line below that line, to which that line connects.` I think its a bug: it should have been blue (and not yellow) because the `|` above commit 8760adec is blue.

Comment: Well, if you think it's a bug, clone the Git repository for Git and start working on the code! 

Comment: I accept your challenge :-). But first, I would like to get your opinion too, do you also think its an issue with how `git --graph` is implemented?

Comment: I've only looked lightly at the `--graph` code and it was kind of scary when I did (as in, it seemed to make a lot of rather rash assumptions about the traversal order).